# Adding CSS class to div with unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So, I am really new to CSS. I am developing a site for the company I work for using WordPress. I know, WordPress "NOOB ALERT."
Anyway, I am using the massive dynamic theme and was hoping to get some help. I created three CSS classes that I want to apply to three different divs that have unique ID's.

- widget-column-1
- widget-column-2
- widget-column-3

And I want to add the following CSS classes to those divs.

- footer-widget-1
- footer-widget-2
- footer-widget-3

respectively to their corresponding number. However, when I tried any of the following methods using the themes built-in "custom JS" editor, the CSS classes failed to apply to the divs. And yes, the CSS works, I manually added the classes in developer mode on Chrome and it gave me the following.
[Screenshot of result w/ css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eGJQ.png)

But, whenever I input any of the following JS solutions, the CSS class is not applied.

```
$(".widget-column-1").addClass("footer-widget-1");

$("#widget-column-1").addClass("footer-widget-1");
```

Neither of these worked, I also tried a few other solutions but can't remember them off the top of my head. Please try to keep in mind that I just started CSS two days ago and am still learning, I don't want my poor little head to get bashed in by some coding giant with a club made of XSS attacks.

[CSS classes I am trying to apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVdFQ.png)

Comment: Solution was implemented. Question no longer needs to be answered, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, what would work for the first widget would be:

```
$('[widgetid="footer-widget-1"]').addClass("footer-widget-1");
```

But, in order for this to work, you'd have to place it in a script that gets loaded on every page you want this to happen. And you probably want to wrap it into a

```
(function($){
    // your jQuery code here...
})(jQuery)
```

---

What I don't really understand is why are you trying to add this class, when you could use the existing class/id/attributes as selectors for the CSS you're trying to apply.

For example:

```
 [widgetid="footer-widget-1"] {
   /* CSS for #widget-column-1 here */
 }
```

...or...

```
 #widget-column-1 {
   /* CSS for #widget-column-1 here */
 }
```

If you add this to your active theme's `style.css` it's going to work.

As a side note, you'll probably find [`CSS Selectors`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [`CSS Combinators`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) useful. Also, in order to become efficient in `CSS` your code should apply. You'll need two things:

- learn to inspect, using developer console of any major browser
- learn [`CSS specificity`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). This will make you understand fast how strong (specific) your selectors need to be in order for a rule to apply, without breaking anything else.

You might also want to tour [`the Codex`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) to make sure you understand how WordPress works.

Comment: This solution worked the best, thanks. I ended up utilizing the 2nd example you gave me and applied it to the style.css in the child theme. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have lost count of the number of "professional" programmer's websites that are made with wordpress.  I have also lost count of how many websites made by freelance developers who use wordpress.  So, not exactly a "noob" thing.

As for your code, try running it on page load:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script> <1--
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".widget-column-1").addClass("footer-widget-1");

    $("#widget-column-1").addClass("footer-widget-1");  
});

</script>
```

Developers generally prefer to narrow down their selectors based on specificness, **instead of adding !important**.  But I'll give you the option to use it, if you wish:

And if that doesn't work, I notice that most wordpress developers add:

```
!important
```

To the end of every CSS declaration...  Basically, this adds priority to your CSS over the template's css.

So, here would be your new code:

```
.footer {
    background: /*stuff here*/ !important;
    background-repeat: /*stuff here*/ !important;
    background-size: /*stuff here*/ !important;
    background-position: /*stuff here*/ !important;
}
```

Comment: Please do not advise on usage of `!important` without clearly specifying downsides. If you are not familiar with them, I suggest not recommending it anymore. [so] is not so much about getting things done, but about getting them done using best practices. Best regards,

Comment: You could start [`here`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/#specificity-in-practice).

Comment: Added a disclaimer.

Comment: I preferred the method I chose from Andrei. But thanks for the suggestions!